# Displaying only children of objects created by the user in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

There is a following relation in my django models:

django `User` --has many-- `Competition` --has many-- `Category` --has many-- `Competitor`

In admin i want to show only Objects created by the logged in `User`.
I can do it for `Competition` - no problem:
In `admin.py` i override `get_queryset` of model admin and assign it to a model:

```
class CompetitionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CompetitionAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user_id=request.user.id)

admin.site.register(Competition,CompetitionAdmin)
```

How can i do the same thing for `Category` and consequently `Competitor`?

Comment: Why can't you do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference foreign key relation with the double underscore notation:

For `Category` if `Category` has a ForeignKey field `competition`:

```
Category.objects.filter(competition__user=request.user)
```

For `Competitor` if `Competitor` has a ForeignKey field `category`:

```
Competitor.objects.filter(category__competition__user=request.user)
```